# Team Explorer Exits After entering user id and password in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

After selecting 'Browse Visual Studio Team Services' (also selected 'Connect to a Team foundation Server or Team Services account') and entering the VSTS user id and password, Team Explorer Everywhere just exits the VSTS window.  After the windows exits, then I'm back at the 'Add Existing Team Project'.

The user/password works fine when I log directly into VSTS via a browser.  In Eclipse, I have tried over 20 times with careful attention to the password, and I can't get past the VSTS login screen cause it just quits after about a second of processing.

Answer (score 0):

> After the windows exits, then I'm back at the 'Add Existing Team
>   Project'.

After you enter the username and passwords, it will go to the 'Add Existing Team Project' page. In this page, it lists all team projects that your account has permission to log in.

Just select the team project you want to connect and click **Finish**.

[image]

By the ways, if you know the URL of your VSTS(`https://{youraccount}.visualstudio.com`), I suggest you could also select '**Connect a Team Foundation Server or Team Service account**' instead of he 'Browse Visual Studio Team Services'.

**Note:**

- When finishing enter username and start to enter passwords, wait few seconds to let the password window pops out.
- Please install a newer version of [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases). I'm using 14.114.0, and everything works fine.

Comment: I tried inputting the URL of my VSTS and waiting for the pop-up, but the select VSTS projects page didn't appear.  Just a flicker on the 'Add Existing Team Project' page.  I have the current version of the Team Explorer Everywhere (ver. 14.114.0.201703081735) and have deleted and reloaded this about 3 times thinking that there is something wrong with the installation of the plug-in.

Comment: @Rob, Please try other version of Team Explore Everywhere. That may work. Maybe 14.111.1 or 14.117.0. https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

Answer (score 0):

Tried the other versions, but it still didn't get to the project selection screen. 
 Over the weekend, the admin group changed the security access and now it works...

Comment: Could you please give more details of the solution and mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, can you add more detail for I am in the same situation and I think it is comain related.  Something screwed up my last AD password change and when it was reset back to a working one, I am now locked out on TFS for Eclipse.